# i can't store data in database when i try to upload

Tags: php, mysql

it gives me an error whenever i try to store the video into the database..i have here a code that can store video into a folder and only save id_no and video_name from database,i want all 5 fields to be stored into my database...can anyone help me with my codes please

```
 <?php session_start();?>
 <?php
 include("session/DBConnection.php");
 include("session/session.php");
 $error = "";
 ?>

 <?php
 $user = $_SESSION['log']['username'];
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = '$user'") or                      die            (mysql_error()); 
        $display = mysql_fetch_array($query);   

if(isset($_POST['upload'])){ 
$mem_id = $display['member_id'];
$stat = "just uploaded a video.";
$date = date("m/d/Y");
$qry = "INSERT INTO updates SET member_id='$mem_id', status='$stat', date='$date'";
$result = mysql_query($qry);
if($result){
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=video.php\">";
 }
}

?>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['video']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0)
{

    $tmpName = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
    $fp = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
    $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
    $content = addslashes($content);
    fclose($fp);

    if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
    }

    else{

            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"],"video_uplaod/" . $_FILES["userfile"]["name"]);
            $user = $_SESSION['log']['username'];
            $today = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
            $location="video_upload/" . $_FILES["userfile"]["name"];
            $video_name=$_POST['video_name'];


            $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_video SET username='$user', video='$location', video_name='$image_name', date_created='$today'";


    echo "File $fileName uploaded";
}

header("video.php");
?>
```

Comment: Could you edit in the error message you're getting?

Comment: What does "it gives me an error" mean? Are we meant to _guess_ that?

Comment: Please tidy your code.

Comment: Your insert statement is incorrect

Comment: "INSERT INTO updates (member_id, status, date) VALUES('$mem_id','$stat','$date')";

Comment: @Mike: `INSERT INTO table SET field=val` is actually valid MySQL syntax. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert.html

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala: Actually, it isn't.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert.html :-)

Comment: So, you get an error?  What would that error happen to be?

Comment: @RocketHazmat I didn't know that was correct syntax, indeed it is... here's sqlfiddle to prove it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/df90b8/2/0

Comment: @RocketHazmat indeed it is, I just tried it out. Good to know

Answer (score 1):

Your INSERT statement is wrong,

`INSERT INTO updates (member_id, status, date) VALUES('$mem_id','$stat','$date')`

should be the right statement, as commented by Mike.

However, you have 3 big problems in your code:

**1) You're using deprecated functions.**

Seriously, stop using mysql_ functions, they're deprecated, they are no longer supported any more by PHP, and they may go away anytime, and when that happens your code will break, and you'll be in a hell of trouble. Use mysqli or PDO instead.

**2) Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection.**

You're not sanitizing user input, `addslashes` is not good enough to prevent SQL injection into your query, if you use mysqli or PDO you'll be able to use prepared statements, so that your code will no longer vulnerable to SQL Injection (it doesn't mean that you shouldn't sanitize user input anyway).

**3) Your code may be vulnerable to a file upload attack.**

You really trust your users, do you?

- What If I'm supposed to upload a video file, but instead of that I
  upload a php file that copies your whole web directory, zips it, and
  send it to my email so that I can see your source code, view your
  database credentials, and open a backdoor to your server and do
  whatever I wish with it?
- When uploading files you shouldn't preserve the original filename,
  you shouldn't save the file "as is", you must process that file and
  make sure that you're handling a video file... DO NOT rely on file
  extension, because I can upload "myfunnyvideo.avi.php" and your file
  extension will pass, because it contains ".avi", and apache will run
  that file because it contains php.
- You shouldn't save the files in a folder that can be guessed by an
  attacker, try to make that as obscure as possible... it's quite
  obvious to see if my file was uploaded to `uploads/` `video_uploads/`
  folder.
- Whatever folder you chose to upload the files to, make sure that
  apache cannot run any script inside of that folder... otherwise, if a
  malicious user guesses the upload directory, he could potentially run
  any php script he wants.

**EDIT**

`INSERT INTO updates SET member_id = ".$mem_id`

is correct syntax, here's proof for those who doesn't believe it:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/df90b8/2/0

Comment: `INSERT INTO table SET field=val` is actually valid MySQL syntax.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert.html

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala: `INSERT INTO table SET field=val` actually works. Try it :)

Comment: I don't think so that it's correct as already 4 people are with me on that.

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala So 4 people can't be wrong? That's an argumentum ad populum, in other words just because a majority agrees with you, it doesn't mean that you're right. (Hitler, someone?) Here's proof that Rocket is right: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/df90b8/2/0

Comment: Ok guy's chill let me give it a try tomorrow will update you.